# GetStream - How to get reactions with_own_children

Tags: laravel, getstream-io

I am using code below to fetch reactions for an activity (with getstream laravel):

```
$lookupField = "activity_id";
$lookupValue = "aaaaaa";
$reactionType="comment";

$params = array(
            'limit' => 5,
            "id_lt" => $idLt,
            'with_activity_data' => 0,
            'with_own_children' => 1,
            //'withOwnChildren' => 1,
            "user_id" => 11111
        );
$reactions = $this->feedClient->reactions()->filter($lookupField, '' . $lookupValue, $reactionType, $params);
```

The parameter `with_own_children` does not seem to work. The response I receive from getstream does not contain "own_children".

I have seen this `next` link in the GET feed response (with `own` and `with_own_children` reactions):

```
    "latest_reactions_extra": {
        "comment": {
            "next": "https://stream-io-api.com/api/v1.0/reaction/activity_id/d4681800-a5a5-xxxx-8080-8001531b6e42/comment/?id_lt=2a012414-6842-460a-bccc-0eb1bac998xx&limit=5&withOwnChildren=true"
        }
    },
```

Is there a way to load reactions withOwnChildren using the reactions API?

Comment: Pass `withOwnReactions` flag because first you need to request parent then children. If parent isn't returned, children can't be returned.

Comment: Actually, I am not trying to load reactions for an activity. I am trying to load reactions using the `activity_id` and `kind`. This is how is shown in the getStream docs:          
`// retrieve all kind of reactions for an activity`
`$client->reactions()->filter("activity_id", "827509c1-2872-11e9-8ec6-0a544dd61b80", "comment");`